# Jenkinsfile get current tag

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-2

Is there a way to get the current tag ( or null if there is none ) for a job in a Jenkinsfile? The background is that I only want to build some artifacts ( android APKs ) when this commit has a tag. 
I tried:

```
env.TAG_NAME
```

and

```
binding.variables.get("TAG_NAME")
```

both are always null - even though this ( https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34520 ) indicates otherwise

Comment: If you don't mind, would you please explain how to handle the result of tag or null in a Jenkinsfile? I am trying to figure out how to use a git tag if present, or a build number if not.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'd consider `returnStdout` rather than writing to a file:

`sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git tag --sort version:refname | tail -1").trim()`

Comment: Yep, this is the correct answer, and was present in the [documentation at the time I gave my answer](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26133).

Comment: how can I set a variable equal to that result?

Comment: also, an easier script is `git describe --tags --long --dirty --always`

Comment: @RobWilkinson by just setting a variable i.e `def foo = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git tag --sort version:refname | tail -1").trim()`

Comment: This command doesn't return the current tag in the current branch, but the latest tag in general.

Comment: building on @RobWilkinson 's response, `git describe` has some useful functionality: `git describe --tags` shows the tag + how many commits since that tag, and a hash id. eg on master, `v1.1.0.2-0-gcf75da0` means no commits since v1.1.0.2, on another branch, `v1.1.0.2-8-g47938eb` means 8 commits since that tag.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. It does not do what the OP asked. Instead, the answer by Florian does. `git tag --contains` or `sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git tag --contains").trim()`

Comment: This returns the latest tag, not the *current* tag.

Answer (score 34):

All the other answers yield an output in any case even if HEAD is not tagged. The question was however to return the *current* tag and "null" if there is nothing like that.

`git tag --contains` yields the tag name name if and only if HEAD is tagged.

For Jenkins Pipelines it should look like this:

`sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git tag --contains").trim()`

Comment: What's the output if there are multiple tags on HEAD?

Comment: Then the git command yields a multiline output. To take multiple tags on HEAD into account you could do something like `git tag --contains | head -1`.

Answer (score 25):

The `TAG_NAME` should work now at least in declarative pipelines.

`When` condition actually filters on this property. `BRANCH_NAME` has the same value.

```
stage('release') {
   when {
     tag 'release-*'
   }
   steps {
     echo "Building $BRANCH_NAME"
     echo "Building $TAG_NAME"
   }
}
```

See https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

Comment: MultiBranch Pipelines need Branch Sources configured for the Behavior "Discover tags".
https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/05/16/pipelines-with-git-tags/

Answer (score 11):

If the current build is a tag build -- as in, `when { buildingTag() }` was "true" -- then the (undocumented) environment variable `BRANCH_NAME` contains the name of the tag being build.

Answer (score 6):

**best way from my site is**:

```
git tag --sort=-creatordate | head -n 1
```

with:

```
latestTag = sh(returnStdout:  true, script: "git tag --sort=-creatordate | head -n 1").trim()
```

Than you can handle with simple regex, for prefix/suffix/version_number what is to do with the tag.

**other solution:**

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```

of course this is the current/latest tag in git. Independent from writing.

```
sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git describe --tags --abbrev=0").trim()
```

Comment: I think this is a much better sort option than `refname`, as it uses git history for determining the most recent tag and not sorting based on tag name.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the git command that does what you want is `git tag --points-at=HEAD` this will list all tags pointing to the current commit or HEAD as it usually called in git. Since HEAD is also the default argument you can also do just `git tag --points-at`.

The pipeline step for executing and returning the git tags one for each line, then becomes:

`sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git tag --points-at")`

Answer (score 1):

Returning **last tag** on current branch, not necessarily on last commit:

```js
sh "git tag --sort version:refname | tail -1 > version.tmp"
String tag = readFile 'version.tmp'
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of **declarative** pipeline following the OP usecase: "do something if this *particular* commit has a tag attached":

```
def gitTag = null
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        checkout(...)
        script {
          gitTag=sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git tag --contains | head -1").trim()
        }
      }
    }
    stage('If tagged') {
      when {
        expression {
          return gitTag;
        }
      }
      steps {
        // ... do something only if there's a tag on this particular commit
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, I have:

- one repository for multiple projects
- each one with their own version tags such as 'MYPROJECT_1.4.23'
- and I want to use the second part of the tag '1.4.23' to tag my images for example

I need to analyze the current tag to check if it concerns my pipeline project (using a PROJECT_NAME variable per project):

```
def gitTag = null
def gitTagVersion = null
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        checkout(...)
        script {
          gitTag=sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git tag --contains | head -1").trim()
          if(gitTag) {
            def parts = gitTag.split('_')
            if( parts.size()==2 && parts[0]==PROJECT_NAME ) {
              gitTagVersion=parts[1]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    stage('If tagged') {
      when {
        expression {
          return gitTagVersion;
        }
      }
      steps {
        // ... do something only if there's a tag for this project on this particular commit
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I'm new at Jenkins and Groovy and that this may be written more simply/cleanly (suggestions welcome).

(with Jenkins 2.268)